# Chebyshev’s inequality meteorite question

Tags: inequality, chebyshev-polynomials

Enceladus is the sixth-largest moon of Saturn. Enceladus is often called the protector of Saturn. Many meteorites that were supposed to fly to Saturn will be affected by the Enceladus's gravity and hit Enceladus. Now suppose that the probability of a meteorite being attracted by Enceladus and hitting Enceladus is 50%. When there are 1600 meteorites flying to Saturn, what is the probability that more than 400 meteorites and less than 1200 meteorites will hit Enceladus?

Hello i am having trouble solving this and would like a step by step process to solve this question using Chebyshev’s inequality.

Comment: To apply Chebyshev, you need to know the standard deviation of the number of meteorites hitting Enceladus. (All of the data are presumed per unit time)

Comment: Hint: Would a Poisson distribution make sense in this case?